# python thread timeout after 10 seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

hi i have a selenium python script that send keys(url and id) to a page in a thread... here is the code

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, idd):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.idd = idd
    def run(self):
        runScript(self.url, self.idd)
        print "Exiting " + self.url

def runScript(url, idd):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/home/wasif/public_html/phantomjs')
    try:
        driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
        driver.get("http://example.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id('url').send_keys(str(url))
        driver.find_element_by_id('id').send_keys(str(idd))
        tble = "urls%s" % (tbl)
        driver.find_element_by_id('table').send_keys(str(tble))
        driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
        #print driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
    except:
        driver.quit()



try:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM urls"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    print "TOTAL RECORDS: "+str(cursor.rowcount)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    count = 0;
    for row in results:
        try:
            domain = row[1]
            idd = row[0]
            myThread(domain, idd).start()
            time.sleep(delay)
        except Exception, e:
            print "error running crawler: "+str(e)

except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
db.close()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

is there any way i can stop the new thread after 10 seconds if it doesn't complete or either stop the `driver` after 10 seconds? any help would be appreciated